# Can I get Uncrustify to fix this newline issue?

Tags: c++, code-formatting, uncrustify

Is there a way to get Uncrustify to remove the newline and whitespace in this if statement?  I can't seem to find an option that fixes this sort of "issue".

```
if (a
    == 5) {
    puts("a is five");
}
```

Comment: Nor me; I can find splitting options, but not joining options.

Comment: Who wrote the code in this way?

Comment: This is just an example.  Obviously it doesn't happen that often, just found a case where Uncrustify falls a little short.